# How to show URL in div current user browsing URL using SignalR ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I'm trying to detect the user browsing URL for showing my dashboard active user and their browsing url.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could do this kind of things, if the client user has go to the browser, you could put the signlar client library to call the server method(e.g sendClientInformation).

Inside this sendClientInformation server hub method, you could call your dashboard method to show the clinet user information.